# For loop not working as desired

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix

I am calculating the distance and velocity between GPS coordinates (lat,long,height) and it appears to work well when I used single values. However, I have a matrix of 79 GPS coordinates (3x79 matrix) and I want to find the distance and speed between each two consecutive points. When I try to use a for loop the output I get is all zeros apart from the first and last value (which are very high).

I am probably doing something silly but I can spot it...any suggestions are appreciated :)

```
for k=1:77
    R=6378.1e3; 

    latDistance = copter_llh(1,k+1) - copter_llh(1,k);
    lonDistance = copter_llh(2,k+1) - copter_llh(2,k);

    a = sin(latDistance / 2) * sin(latDistance / 2) + cos(copter_llh(1,k))...
      *cos(copter_llh(1,k+1)) * sin(lonDistance / 2) * sin(lonDistance / 2);
    c = 2 *atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));

    distance = R * c * 1000; % convert to meters

    height = copter_llh(3,k+1) - copter_llh(3,k); 
    distance = sqrt((distance^ 2) + (height^2)); 
    velocity = distance/0.1*60; 
    % stepsize =0.1min ___speed in m/s 
    distance(:,k)=(distance); 
    velocity(:,k)=(velocity); 
end %-----
```

Comment: It's to add the height component of the point to the lat/long distance. I it doesn't become a matrix from that.

Comment: I think I know why it's happening.  Check my answer.

Comment: The formula works when I specify the points I want directly, just not when I am using the for loop

Comment: Yes, and the way your code is structured is that it won't work if you have multiple points within a `for` loop :)  It only works because your code is accessing the variables in such a way that if the inputs were just single points, then it will output a single point.  It doesn't work as expected when you start using matrices of points, and I explain why in my answer below.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. That makes a lot of sense... I am a MATLAB idiot  - it's official haha.

Comment: Oh you're welcome :) Trust me we've all been there... including me!  I also added in a blurb where you can definitely do this without a `for` loop.  I haven't tested it yet as I don't have your data to test it on, but I'm quite certain it will work.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are reusing your `distance` variable in an unintentional way, as well as your `velocity` variable at the end of your `for` loop.  You're mutating the `distance` variable, and then trying to reshape it as a matrix.  You'll need to change this variable, and then call where you want to store your matrix as something else.  Also, `distance` and `velocity` look like they're single arrays, and so the `:` accessing for the first dimension is superfluous.  As such, try doing this instead:

```
distance = zeros(1,77); %// NEW - Preallocate distance array
velocity = zeros(1,77); %// NEW - Preallocate velocity array
R=6378.1e3; %// NEW - Leave outside for loop.  Constant at each iteration
for k=1:77

    latDistance = copter_llh(1,k+1) - copter_llh(1,k);
    lonDistance = copter_llh(2,k+1) - copter_llh(2,k);

    a = sin(latDistance / 2) * sin(latDistance / 2) + cos(copter_llh(1,k))...
      *cos(copter_llh(1,k+1)) * sin(lonDistance / 2) * sin(lonDistance / 2);
    c = 2 *atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));

    dist = R * c * 1000; %// convert to meters - NEW - change variable

    height = copter_llh(3,k+1) - copter_llh(3,k); 
    %// stepsize =0.1min ___speed in m/s 
    distance(k) = sqrt((dist^ 2) + (height^2)); %// NEW - Assign directly to distance array
    velocity(k) = distance/0.1*60; %// NEW - Assign directly to velocity array
end %-----
```

This code should now store 77 distances and velocities stored in `distance` and `velocity` respectively.  Try that and let me know if it works!

---

## Sidenote

You can compute this in a completely vectorized way without any `for` loops.  You can use [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to compute those neighbouring distances for you.  As such, you can actually do something like this:

```
R=6378.1e3;
latDistance = diff(copter_llh(1,:)); % // NEW
lonDistance = diff(copter_llh(2,:)); %// NEW

a = sin(latDistance / 2) .* sin(latDistance / 2) + cos(copter_llh(1,1:end-1))...
  .*cos(copter_llh(1,2:end)) .* sin(lonDistance / 2) .* sin(lonDistance / 2);
c = 2 *atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a));

dist = R * c * 1000; %// convert to meters - NEW - change variable

height = diff(copter_llh(3,:));
distance = sqrt((dist.^2) + (height.^2));  %// NEW
velocity = distance/0.1*60; %// NEW
```

The above code should be equivalent to your `for` loop method, but remember to always write code that makes sense to you first and works before you start doing any optimizations.  That's the best way to code!